# Anaconda Jupyter notebook can't open with browser

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I want to use 'R' with Jupyter notebook. Then, try this installation code.

```
conda install -c r r-essentials
```

After download, i can't open the jupyter notebook. I think the python is colliding with R. And, I removed it.
Anaconda Jupyter-notebook still can't open with this error.

```
[I 16:43:11.334 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 4 kernels found
[I 16:43:12.882 NotebookApp] [nb_anacondacloud] enabled
[I 16:43:12.885 NotebookApp] [nb_conda] enabled
[I 16:43:12.910 NotebookApp] ✓ nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
[W 16:43:12.910 NotebookApp] ✗ nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module named 'nbbrowserpdf'
[C 16:43:12.912 NotebookApp] Running as root is not recommended. Use --allow-root to bypass.
```

Using Ubuntu 16.04, Python-3.5.5 Anaconda-4.2.0 Jupyter-notebook 5.4.1

I'm only access jupyter notebook in terminal with this code

```
sudo jupyter notebook --allow-root
```

How can i access in this in anacodna-navigator?

Comment: why do you run `sudo jupyter notebook` instead of `jupyter notebook`

Comment: if i type the 'jupyter notebook' code then the program can't make new file. Almost thing is denied. Anaconda is same. 'sudo anaconda-navigator' is needed

Comment: did you install conda as a root? You can install it as normal user [link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux)

Comment: also checkout this [post](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-you-need-python-environments-and-how-to-manage-them-with-conda-85f155f4353c) about environments

Comment: If I can't solve I'll try it. Thank you!

Comment: it's rocommanded to install Anaconda in /opt/, you can use it with all user, also when you run jupyter as root you have to add `--allow-root`

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall anaconda and search for Anaconda Navigator in Spotlight (if you use Windows search for it in Microsoft Start) open it and you should see Jupyter notebook aswell as other IDEs such as Spyder, Jupyter lab and Datalore. Once you find it click launch below the icon for Jupyter notebook and it should take you right there.                   If you need help installing Anaconda this should help>>>  https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os.html